# Example of inequivalent valuations inducing the same topology

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, field-theory, problem-solving, valuation-theory

**Few definitions:**

1. Let $F$ be a field. We define a valuation on $F$ as a function $v:K\to G\cup \infty$ (where $(G,+,<)$ is an ordered abelian group) that satisfy:

$v(a)=\infty$ iff $a=0_F$.

$v(ab)=v(a)+v(b)$ for all $a,b\in F^*$.

$v(a+b)\geq min\{v(a),v(b)\}$.

2. The valuation group of $(F,v)$ is $G_v:=v(F^*)\subset G$.
3. Let $v:F\to G_1\cup \infty, w:F\to G_2\cup \infty$ valuations on $F$. Then they are equivalent if there exists an isomorphism of ordered groups $a:(G_v,+,<) \to (G_w,+,<)$ such that $w(x)=a(v(x))$ for all $x\in F^*$
4. Given valuations: $v:F\to G_v, w:F\to G_w$ then
   $v,w$ are equivalent iff $O_v=O_w$, where $O_v: \{x\in F: v(x)\geq 0\}$.

**Question** (**edited**) ((My main concern is in parts 3, 4):

Let $F$ be a field with a valuation $v$ and an ordered abelian group $G_v=(Z^2,+,<_l)$.
Let $p_1:Z^2\to Z$ be the map $p_1(a,b)=a$. Show that:

1. $v'(x)=p_1(v(x))$ ($v'(0)=\infty$) is a valuation on $F$ with $G_{v'}=Z$.
2. $v'$ induces the same topology as $v$ on $F$.
3. If two valuations induce the same topology on a field $F$, they do not need to be equivalent.
4. Let $F$ be a field with a valuation $v$ with valuation group $G$ and $G'$ is an orderded abelian group. Let $p:G\to G'$ an order preserving surjective homomorphism.
   Show that $v_2(a)=p(v(a))$ (with $v_2(0)=\infty$), is a valuation on $F$ that induces the same topology as $v$ on $F$.

Here $<_l$ is the order defined by:
$(a_1,b_1)<_l (a_2,b_2)$ if $a_1<a_2$ or $a_1=a_2, b_1<b_2$.

---

My trial:

In 1.

--we're given that $v'(0)=\infty$.

-- if $x,y \in F^*$ then $v(x), v(y)\in Z^2$ so I can write $v(x)=(a_1,b_1), v(y)=(a_2,b_2)$ (where $a_1, b_1, a_2, b_2 \in Z$), then $p_1(v(x))=p_1(a_1,b_1)=a_1$ and $p_1(a_2,b_2)=a_2$.

So, $v'(xy)=p_1(v(xy))=p_1(v(x)+v(y))=p_1((a_1,b_1)+(a_2,b_2))=p_1((a_1+a_2,b_1+b_2))=a_1+a_2=..=v'(x)+v'(y)$ (since $v$ is a valuation).

--If $x,y\in F$, we need to show
$v'(x+y)\geq min\{ v'(x),v'(y)\}$.
If $(a_1,b_1)\leq_l (a_2,b_2)$ then $a_1\leq_l a_2$.
So, if $v(x+y)\geq min\{v(x),v(y)\}$ and we assume that  $v(x)\leq v(y)$ then $v'(x+y)\geq p_1(v(x))=v'(x)$ and if we assume that $v(y)\leq v(x) $ by symmetry we get that $v'(x+y)\geq v'(y)$, therefore $v'(x+y)\geq min\{v'(x),v'(y)\}$.

And, $G_{v'}=v'(F^*)=p_1(v(F^*))=p_1(Z^2)=Z$.

In 2.
The topology induced by $v$ is given by the basis $\{B_g(a): a\in F, g\in G_v\}$ where $B_{g}^v(a)=\{x\in F: v(x-a)>g\}$.
So, if I want to see that $v, v'$ induce the same topology on $F$, it is enough to show that a $v'$-neighborhood of any point $x_0\in F$ is contained in the $v$-neighborhood of $x_0$ (i.e the open ball in the $v'$ topology, around $x_0$ is contained in the open ball in the $v$ topology around $x_0$) and vise versa.

-- If $x\in B_{(a, b)}^v(x_0)$ then $v(x-x_0)>(a,b)$, write $v(x-x_0)=(c,d)$ so $c>a$ or $c=a, d=b$. Therefore,
$v'(x-x_0)=p_1(v(x-x_0))=p_1(c,d)>c\geq a$
So $x\in B_{a-1}^{v'}(x_0)$.

--  if $x\in B_{a-1}^{v'}(x_0)$ then $v'(x-x_0)>a-1$ but this the same as
$p_1(v(x-x_0))>a-1$. Write $v(x-x_0)=(c,d)$ so $p_1(c,d)>a-1$ then $c>a-1$. Then,
$(c,d)>_l (a-1,b)$ therefore $v(x-x_0)>(a-1,b)$(for some $b,d$).
This shows that $x\in B_{(a-1,b)}^v$.
In total we have:
$B_{(a, b)}^v(x_0) \subset B_{a-1}^{v'}(x_0) \subset B_{(a-1,b)}^v$. Does this look fine?

In 3. The value groups of $v,v'$ are $Z^2, Z$ (respectively) which are not isomorphic as groups. But what a simple example of such valuations can I consider?

In 4. First, $v_2$ is a valuation:

--we're given that $v_2(0)=\infty$.

-- let $a,b\in F^*$ then
$v_2(ab)=p(v(ab))=$(v is a valuation) $p(v(a)+v(b))=$($p$ is a homomorphism)= $p(v(a))+p(v(b))=v_2(a)+v_2(b)$.

--Let $a,b\in F$ then $v_2(a+b)=p(v(a+b))\geq$ ($p$ is order preserving) $p(min\{v(a),v(b)\})=$ (assume $v(a)\leq v(b)$) $p(v(a))=v_2(a)$ and similarly, if $v(b)\leq v(a)$ then
$v_2(a+b)\geq v_2(b)$, so, $v_2(a+b)\geq min\{v_2(a),v_2(b)\}$.

But I did not use that $p$ is surjective in the above calculation!

To show that both valuation induce the same topology:

We find elements of the base such that,

$B_{g_1}^{v}(x_0) \subseteq B_g^{v_2}(x_0) \subseteq 
B_{g_2}^{v}(x_0)$. ($x_0, g$ are arbitrary).

If $x\in B_{a}^v(x_0)$ then $v(x-x_0)=c>a$.
Then $v_2(x-x_0)=p(v(x-x_0))=p(c)>p(a)$ ($p$ is order preserving), but can I say now that $x\in B_{p(a)}^{v_2}$ and so $B_{a}^v(x_0)\subset B_{p(a)}^{v_2}(x_0)$?

Now, let $x\in B_{a}^{v_2}(x_0)$ so $v_2(x-x_0)>a$ but $p(v(x-x_0))=v_2(x-x_0)>a$ then how one can say that $v(x-x_0)>..$?

It would be highly appreciated if you could help me improve my way of thinking and finish the points that I did not succeed to deal with.

Comment: Is not 3 answered by the example in 1 and 2?

Comment: Also, the question has been edited about 10 times since the answer was posted, which makes it hard to understand what the answer talks about and what is actually asked about now.

Answer (score 1):

For $v_2$ it is not true that it is a valuation.

If $v(a)=(0,0)$, $v(c)=(1,-1)$, $b=c-a$ then $v(c)>v(-a)$ gives that $v(b) =v(-a)=(0,0)$

so $v_2(a+b) = v_2(c)=-1$ is not $\ge \min(v_2(a),v_2(b))=0$

Comment: Can you take a look please at my edit @reuns